# React Navigation - Common component across screens in DrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

in my app I have a drawer which contains some screens. In each screen there's a common component, let's call it `Footer`:
[image: Footer]

For more details, let's take a look at the design of my app:

**- The drawer**
[image: Drawer]

("Transactions", "Statistics", "Settings" ... are stack navigators)

**- The Transactions screen**
[image: Transactions screen]

I tried these approaches:
- Put the `Footer` component in the same level with the drawer. There's a problem doing this: when the drawer is opened, it's behind the `Footer`
[image]
- Add the `Footer` component in every screen. This isn't an elegant solution because multiple `Footer` component will be created, and I have to create a redux state to synchronize these instances of this component.

**Note:** I'm using react-native version 0.44 and react-navigation version 1.5.2

Comment: You need to have tab navigation, inside your drawer navigation. ref : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html